How to Eliminate Visible Edges in Matplotlib pcolormesh Plot?
I'm working with Matplotlib to create a heightmap visualization using pcolormesh, but I'm encountering an issue where the edges of the mesh grid are visible in the output image, despite setting edgecolors='none'. This results in an unwanted wireframe-like appearance on the plot near the edge of the colorplot. I'm trying to achieve a smooth, uninterrupted surface visualization.
image
Despite setting edgecolors='none' and testing with rasterized=True, the wireframe still appear in the saved figure. I've also tried increasing the resolution and adjusting the colormap. When I set color map at 50% opacity i see that the meshgrid comes through my colormap. Like this pic shows (with viridis and alpha=0.5) image
How can I remove or hide these mesh edges to achieve a completely smooth surface visualization?
Additional Information:
Python version: 3.x
Matplotlib version: latest
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Here's a simplified version of my code that shows the same artifact if you zoom in to the edge:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from os.path import join

# Sample data for demonstration
x = np.random.rand(1000)
y = np.random.rand(1000) * 100  # Y values scaled to simulate height data
z = np.random.rand(1000)

# Convert data to NumPy arrays
x_np = np.array(x)
y_np = np.array(y)
z_np = np.array(z)

# Define grid resolution
heightmap_resolution = (512, 512)

# Create a grid
grid_x, grid_z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(np.min(x_np), np.max(x_np), heightmap_resolution[0]),
                             np.linspace(np.min(z_np), np.max(z_np), heightmap_resolution[1]))

# Interpolate Y values on the grid
points = np.column_stack((x_np, z_np))
grid_y = griddata(points, y_np, (grid_x, grid_z), method='cubic')

# Plot setup
fig_width, fig_height = 210 / 25.4, 297 / 25.4  # Dimensions in inches
dpi = 1440  # High DPI for detailed output

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height), dpi=dpi)
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])  # Use full area of the figure
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['white', 'black'])
c = ax.pcolormesh(grid_x, grid_z, grid_y, cmap=cmap, shading='gouraud', edgecolors='none', rasterized=True)
ax.axis('off')  # Turn off the axis

# Save the figure
output_dir = r"C:\test" #CHANGE THIS PATH 
heightmap_name = 'out_plot_height_map.png'
plt.savefig(join(output_dir, heightmap_name), format='png', dpi=dpi, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.close(fig)

I tried this code, but this 'pixelates' the output. I need the gradient that comes with shading='gouraud', as this heightmap will be used in a manufacturing step and the steps form the pixels are a no-go
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(fig_width, fig_height), dpi=dpi)
im = ax.imshow(grid_y, extent=[np.min(x_np), np.max(x_np), np.min(z_np), np.max(z_np)], interpolation='bicubic', cmap='viridis', aspect='auto')
ax.axis('off')
plt.savefig(join(output_dir, heightmap_name), format='png', dpi=dpi, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.close(fig)


In your viridis image, the edges are visible due to the borders of adjacent cells overlapping. To avoid this, alpha should be set to 1 (you can create a whiter looking colormap if you need that whiter look).  Could you clarify what exactly you want different in your first and second code example?   Due to the unordered and random x and z values, you are creating a weird grid_y with a highly overlapping and self-crossing grid (this causes the staircase effects).  If you have unordered x,y,z values as input, you can call ax.tricontourf(x, z, y, levels=256, cmap=...).

There is an open bug report for this but I thought it only happened when plotting with transparency https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/27016

yeah, sorry, mesh is just an example (as shitty one i must confess, but any deformed grid in just z-axis shows this). It seems the issue is exactly like referenced bug-report (i was unaware of this, thanks for pointing this out). Any workarounds that you are aware of? `i already tried edgecolors='none'.
